# How to get Best Practical RT configuration

Tags: perl, bug-tracking

How to get Best Practical's RT configuration (list of users, queues, possible values for status field, possible values for custom field) via its REST interface? Or may be there is some web page where this information can be easily parsed from? I found sources for REST interface in `rt-3.8.7.tar.gz/rt-3.8.7/share/html/REST/1.0` but I know little of perl and don't understand how these scripts are executed and what they are doing.

Comment: It sounds like you should contact their support department. Or at least provide a link with more information.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried: http://wiki.bestpractical.com/view/REST

Comment: Yeap. This page say nothing about fetching RT configuration.